# For what is openFileOutput() used for?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I have this snippet of code.
Can someone please help what '0' attribute in openFileOutput stands for in the following code?

```
public void Save(String fileName) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out =
            new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName, 0));
        out.write(EditText1.);
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Note Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: for Context.MODE_PRIVATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> int: Operating mode.
>   Value is either 0 or combination of MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE or MODE_APPEND.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Using a constant is recommended, but 0 is `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

Comment: Note that `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` and `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` are deprecated as of API 17.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`Context.openFileOutput`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)), the 0 represents the mode for opening the file. In this case, 0 is a synonym for [`MODE_PRIVATE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE):

> File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).

So only the application that created the file can access it later. Another option is [`MODE_APPEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_APPEND) which opens the file at its current endpoint and adds extra data to it.